# TypeError in my code. Using selection sort to sort values at a certain index

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort, columnsorting

I want my selection sort to sort the values in a certain column (index 3) however I get this message when I run my code.

The error I receive is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxG2G.png

```
def selectionSort(lst2):
  size = len(lst2)
  for i in range(size):
    min_idx = i[3]
    for j in range(min_idx + 1, size):
      if lst2[j] < lst2[min_idx]:
        min_idx = j
    lst2[i[3]], lst2[min_idx] = lst2[min_idx], lst2[i[3]]

lst2 = lst
selectionSort(lst2)
print(lst2)
```

Comment: What do you expect `i` and `i[3]` to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is much better to copy/paste your error text into the question so that it is immediately visible and also searchable for future users of the questions.

To understand the error message "'int' object is not subscriptable:"

- The 'int' object here is `i`
- `[3]` is the subscript, which is being applied to `i` in `i[3]`
- So, the error is telling you that you've tried to find the 4th element within `i`, but `i` is just an integer and there are no subelements.

Comment: apologies for that, when i tried typing in my error text, it said that there were other questions similar and i couldnt find the answer to them so i had to type it as such. thanks for the help.